# NewRelic on Heroku: Cannot find or read /tmp/build_2aqfzcy5zyv4m/config/newrelic.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, newrelic

I'm trying to setup the newrelic add-on for Heroku.  I'm running on Rails 3.2.3.

I have followed the instructions from here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#addon_installation

When I push to Heroku, I get a message that says:

```
Cannot find or read /tmp/build_2aqfzcy5zyv4m/config/newrelic.yml
```

And when I go to https://heroku.newrelic.com/ it tells me to setup my app and points me back to the add-on installation instructions.

Any idea what is going on here and how to resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Newrelic gem should automaticaly check for config in /config/newrelic.yml. You can use https://raw.github.com/gist/2253296/newrelic.yml as template.

If your app for some reason won't search for the file in this location, or you have file in other location, you can specify path using heroku config. With heroku toolbelt you can use command:

```
heroku config:set NRCONFIG=/config/newrelic.yml
```